# How to hide div after click on an element using pure css?

Tags: css, vue.js

Actually, i'm building a CSS Main Menu in Vue, it works fine when mouse hover it'll popup while hidden when mouse move out, but how can i also hide the menu when click on "a" hyperlink?

I've try ".menu a:active { display: none; }", but failed.

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
}

.main:hover .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <button>Main Menu Title</button>
    <div class="menu">
        <a>Sub Menu Title</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.menu a:active { display: none; }` will work only when mouse button will be pushed until you release it.
Unfortunately you won't be able to implement this idea using pure CSS.
I would recommend you to add additional class on click, for example:

```
.hidden {
    display: hidden;
}
```

But you will have to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In my own view, I think you are having a very powerful tool with you but you are under using it. Vue.js can do the task you want effortlessly.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const showMenu = ref(false)
const ToggleMenu = () => {
    showMenu.value = !showMenu.value  
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="main">
    <button @click="ToggleMenu">Main Menu Title</button>
    <div v-if="showMenu" class="menu">
        <a>Sub Menu Title</a>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<style>
.menu a {
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I did know vue data binding, but what i need is the menu auto show up when mouse hover, and auto hide when click the hyperlink, your answer doesn’t fit for me

Comment: CSS can show on hover but when clicked can be a problem with CSS, you are limited to utilizing properties like active, focus etc which will not provide a concrete solution for your problem